# How can I change the color of a Spine slot or attachment in Phaser?

Tags: phaser-framework, spine

How can I change the color of a Spine slot in Phaser? (I'm using Phaser version 3.60.0-beta.22)

I can find an attachment, and it should be possible to change the color by creating a new color (of the type `spine.Color`) like this:

```ts
const slot skeleton.findSlot('slot-name');
slot.color = new spine.Color(1,1,1); // IDE doesn't complain, but I get ReferenceError at runtime
```

However, I get a runtime error: "ReferenceError: spine is not defined".
I followed this [blog post](https://blog.ourcade.co/posts/2020/phaser-3-parcel-typescript-spine/) to include the `SpinePlugin` in my TypeScript project. Loading and adding Spine game objects to the scene work fine. I just don't know how to create a new Color and apply it to the slot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `Color` Class from the `plugin` property, of the *`scene.spine`* property

```
slot.color = new this.spine.plugin.Color(1, 1, 1);
```

**Update *(based on question in the comment):***

Here *possible hacky* typescript syntax fix:

```
slot.color = new (this as any).spine.plugin.Color(1, 1, 1);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I assume `this` is the `scene`.
I also had to make a few adjustments to make it work. I had to write `scene['spine'].plugin.webgl.Color(1,1,1)`. I had to write `['spine']` because I got the following error in the IDE otherwise "Property 'spine' does not exist on type 'Scene'." Do you happen to know how to prevent that error from appearing in the IDE? (I'm using TypeScript)

Comment: @John I no typescript expert, but quick fix could be to write `new (this as any).spine.plugin.Color(1,1,1)`, like this there should be no error. And yes with `this` I meant the `scene`, I just wrote it as I would in the `create` function.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comment. I don't know why I had to write `webgl` after `plugin` to make it work though. The answer helped me solve the question, so I will accept it.

Comment: @John thanks for the acceptance. the `webgl` is also interesting to me, it could have to do with the plugin version, or so. I based my answer on [spine.d.ts from the github master](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/master/types/spine.d.ts) since I didn't have a current, spine project. I'm glad I could help, happy coding/ _phaser-ing_. :)